# Editing a freeform submission entry

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I have a custom plugin where I get a freeform submission by token. I woud like to change a value in this submission and resave the submission. When I try this the old form data gets overwritten.

```
$submission = Freeform::getInstance()->submissions->getSubmissionByToken($submissionToken);

$submission->setFormFieldValues(['customField' => $customFieldValue]);

// method 1, doesn't accept type submission, should be form     
Freeform::getInstance()->submissions->storeSubmission($submission);
// method 2, old data get's overwritten, current submissiontoken changes
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($submission);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `setFormFieldValues()` has an optional second parameter related to overriding values...

`public function setFormFieldValues(array $values, bool $override = true)`

So, changing...

`$submission->setFormFieldValues(['customField' => $customFieldValue]);`

... to...

`$submission->setFormFieldValues(['customField' => $customFieldValue], false);`

may help with the override issue.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution. I already had found this answer myself. No idea how I missed it. Thanks for your reply.